# Can mods improve your comments and post them with your name?

Tags: support, moderator-abilities

I just saw, that I left the nearly same comment twice, whilst the link of the second one was improved. I'm pretty sure I only posted the first one, hence the question in the title. 
I'm referring to my comment on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52244726/how-to-add-videos-in-a-windows-form-applctn) question.

Comment: It's not a mod who did this. You likely flagged the question? There are some auto-comments that are put in your name if you take certain moderation actions

Comment: @Patrice That makes sense...Guess I never flagged something as duplicate before :D

Comment: The comment on that post was added by the system because you flagged the post as a duplicate.

Comment: FYI: Mods can edit your comments, but we almost never will. If your comment needs editing, we'll probably just delete it. We cannot *create* new comments with your name attached though.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up!

Comment: @meagar I never knew mods could edit comments, does it still follow the 5 minute window to us mortals?

Comment: @WhatsThePoint No, the 5 minute rule doesn't apply to mod-edits for comments.

Comment: @meagar does it also show it has been edited too?

Comment: @WhatsThePoint It will, but it will not show who has edited it. If you'd like, I can edit one of your comments so you can see this, instead of having me describe it :)

Comment: @meagar sure edit this one :) [meagar added this]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Mods cannot post a comment in another user's name.*

What happened here is that you posted a comment manually, then flagged the post. The second comment was posted automatically when you flagged.

*Usually,* the system will see the first comment and not post the auto-comment. Something about this case, possible how the link was formatted, made the system ignore your first comment.

---

<sub>* I think there is an exception, in that if a mod converts an answer to a comment (a rare occurrence) it is posted under the other user's name- But that's not the mod manually posting a comment.</sub>

Comment: The system will only refrain from posting the "possible duplicate..." comment if someone else has already flagged or voted and thus triggered a previous, system-generated comment for the same target.

Comment: @Shog9 That's odd, because I've posted manual comments on a new question (admittedly here on Meta) and not had an auto-comment generated. =/

Comment: And about the exception, I think that's fine, because every single word was writen by the user assigned the to the comment, not by the moderator. The mod merely migrated from one location to another.

Comment: Mods can edit comments though, can't they? So they could edit a comment to entirely new content (though would hopefully never do such a thing).

Comment: @TylerH They can, though I'm not sure I could call that posting a comment under another user's name... But that would be a technicality...